# Use One Temporary File Many Times

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using SoundStrecher class to change the compression rate of my Audio. The new audio is being written in another file which i have.

```
    static void processWave(string fileIn, string fileOut, float newTempo = 1.4f, float newPitch = 1, float newRate = 1)
    {
        WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(fileIn);

        int numChannels = reader.WaveFormat.Channels, sampleRate = reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        int bitPerSample = reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 16;

        SoundStretcher stretcher = new SoundStretcher(sampleRate, numChannels);
        WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(fileOut, new WaveFormat(sampleRate, 16, numChannels));

        stretcher.Tempo = newTempo;
        stretcher.Pitch = newPitch;
        stretcher.Rate = newRate;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        short[] buffer2 = null;

        if (bitPerSample == 8)
            buffer2 = new short[BUFFER_SIZE];

        bool finished = false;

        while (true)
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            if (!finished)
            {
                bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    finished = true;
                    stretcher.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bitPerSample == 16)
                        stretcher.PutSamplesFromBuffer(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    else if (bitPerSample == 8)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
                            buffer2[i] = (short)((buffer[i] - 128) * 256);
                        stretcher.PutSamples(buffer2);
                    }
                }
            }
            bytesRead = stretcher.ReceiveSamplesToBuffer(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            if (finished && bytesRead == 0)
                break;
        }


        reader.Close();
        writer.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processWave("D:\\us1.wav","D:\\vs2.wav");
        WaveOut obj = new WaveOut();
        WaveFileReader h = new WaveFileReader("D:\\vs2.wav");
        obj.Init(h);
        obj.Play();
    }
```

I face this exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'D:\vs2.wav' because it is being used by another process.
```

when i change my form load event to:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            processWave("D:\\us1.wav", "D:\\vs2.wav");
            WaveOut obj = new WaveOut();
            WaveFileReader h = new WaveFileReader("D:\\vs2.wav");
            obj.Init(h);
            obj.Play();
        }
```

How do i keep using vs2.wav as my temporary file both the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping up the writer in processWave with a using statement:

```
static void processWave(string fileIn, string fileOut, float newTempo = 1.4f, float newPitch = 1, float newRate = 1)
{
    using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(fileIn))
    {

        int numChannels = reader.WaveFormat.Channels, sampleRate = reader.WaveFormat.SampleRate;
        int bitPerSample = reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample;

        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 16;

        SoundStretcher stretcher = new SoundStretcher(sampleRate, numChannels);

        using (WaveFileWriter writer = new WaveFileWriter(fileOut, new WaveFormat(sampleRate, 16, numChannels)))
        {

            stretcher.Tempo = newTempo;
            stretcher.Pitch = newPitch;
            stretcher.Rate = newRate;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            short[] buffer2 = null;

            if (bitPerSample == 8)
                buffer2 = new short[BUFFER_SIZE];

            bool finished = false;

            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;
                if (!finished)
                {
                    bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        finished = true;
                        stretcher.Flush();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (bitPerSample == 16)
                            stretcher.PutSamplesFromBuffer(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        else if (bitPerSample == 8)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
                                buffer2[i] = (short)((buffer[i] - 128) * 256);
                            stretcher.PutSamples(buffer2);
                        }
                    }
                }
                bytesRead = stretcher.ReceiveSamplesToBuffer(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
                writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                if (finished && bytesRead == 0)
                    break;
            }


            writer.Close();
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        processWave("D:\\us1.wav", "D:\\vs2.wav");
        WaveOut obj = new WaveOut();

        using (WaveFileReader h = new WaveFileReader("D:\\vs2.wav"))
        {
            obj.Init(h);
            obj.Play();
        }
    }

    /*
    processWave("D:\\us1.wav","D:\\vs2.wav");
    WaveOut obj = new WaveOut();

    using (WaveFileReader h = new WaveFileReader("D:\\vs2.wav"))
    {
        obj.Init(h);
        obj.Play();
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: i updated the example.  you should probably be disposing all of the disposable instances

Comment: Now the track is not being played

Comment: Manually as in Windows Media Player.  Is the processed file being created and stretched properly?

Comment: When i play it in vlc, the file is being played without any changes.The original content of vs2.wav is being played. No modifications are being reflected

Comment: Where can I find the SoundStretcher assemblies?

Comment: is it part of naudio?

Comment: yes. SoundStretcher is the class used in c# for using soundtouch

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by using the playbackstopped event of waveout..the error was happening because after the audio was completed, the reader did not leave the file, i.e the it was still open in read mode..all i did was close the reader after it was done with playing, thus closing my file from read mode

code:

```
  WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();
  waveOut.PlaybackStopped += obj_PlaybackStopped;
```

and in the obj_PlaybackStopped event I closed my wavefilereader:

```
  waveFileReader.Close();
```